# Why is 0 vs 0.0 causing a precision problem?

Tags: machine-precision, precision-and-accuracy

I wasn't sure what to title this Question.
I tried calculating different forms of a continued fraction, and I found that I get a correct result when I set d to 0 but a wrong result (in the final two terms) if I set d to 0.0

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
t = Sqrt[17];
d = 0.0;
n = 11;
a = ConstantArray[0, n];
Do[a[[i]] = Floor[t + d]; t = 1/(t - Floor[t + d]), {i, 1, n}];
a

{4, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 7, 4}
```

I only caught this because I happen to know that this series should end in infinite 8's.

When I try to calculate the form of continued fractions that allows negative terms, I get the correct series from d=1/2 but wrong terms if d=.5.  So I gather that this problem has something to do with precision and using rational numbers instead of floats but why is this happening for zero?  Is Mathematica adding 0.0 incorrectly?

Comment: The presence of **any** machine precision number (including `0.0`) will result in the calculation being done with machine precision.

Comment: By using an extended precision version of `0` you can get a small speedup from using numbers instead of full symbolic expressions but without sacrificing accuracy. Try ```d=0``1```.

Comment: Also in terms of programming style this is probably faster: ``d + NestList[1/(# - Floor[# + d]) &, t, 200] // 
  Floor // RepeatedTiming``

Answer (score 4):

Your algorithm is probing the limits of machine precision numbers.

When you add `Sqrt[17]+0` you get $\sqrt{17}$ with infinite precision:

```
Sqrt[17] + 0
(* Sqrt[17] *)
```

When you add `Sqrt[17]+0.0` you get much less precision:

```
Sqrt[17] + 0.0 // FullForm
(* 4.123105625617661` *)
```

The number you're effectively dealing with in the `d=0.0` case is not $t=\sqrt{17}$ but

```
SetPrecision[Sqrt[17] + 0.0, ∞]
(* 4642204239785223/1125899906842624 *)
```

which is the closest available machine-precision number to $\sqrt{17}$.

If you change your code to

```
t = 4642204239785223/1125899906842624;
d = 0;
n = 11;
a = ConstantArray[0, n];
Do[a[[i]] = Floor[t + d]; t = 1/(t - Floor[t + d]), {i, 1, n}];
a
```

you get a similar answer to the `d=0.0` case:

```
(* {4, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 7, 2} *)
```

Another way of seeing this is that you're doing a continued-fraction representation, which differs when you convert a number to its machine-precision representation:

```
ContinuedFraction[Sqrt[17]]
(* {4, {8}} *)
ContinuedFraction[Sqrt[17] // N]
(* {4, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8} *)
```

Notice that the builtin `ContinuedFraction` command stops before spitting out "wrong" digits due to machine-precision issues.

Answer (score 1):

Two comments rolled into one.

Try using extended precision numbers like:

```
d = 0``1
```

Also try a different programming style to get things cleaner and a bit faster:

```
t = Sqrt[17];
d = 0``1;
d + NestList[1/(# - Floor[# + d]) &, t, 200] // Floor // RepeatedTiming

{0.0055, {4, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 
  8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8,
   8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 
  8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8,
   8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 
  8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8,
   8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 
  8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8,
   8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 
  8}}
```